# dojox.widget.Toaster messages will not display

Tags: php, dojo

I've added a Toaster div using:

```
<div dojoType="dojox.widget.Toaster" duration="0" messageTopic="myMessages" positionDirection="tr-right" id="toasted"></div>
```

I've added the require:

```
dojo.require("dojox.widget.Toaster");
```

and the CSS for the theme and also for the Toaster:

```
dojo-release-1.6.0/dojox/widget/Toaster/Toaster.css
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css
```

Upon a click event I've added a message to publish:

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    dojo.connect(dojo.byId('strapline'), 'onclick', function(event) {
        dojo.publish('myMessages', [{ message: 'Qwerty', type: "error", duration: 0}])
    });
});
```

Can you see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things you can check:

- Paths: do all the resources have correct urls and actually load? Firebug or similar browser console should be able to tell you this
- parseOnLoad: By default, the parser is not loaded and doesn't run, so if your declarative widget there won't be instantiated unless you have set dojo.config.parseOnLoad to true. See this [dojo config tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/dojo_config/) for more details.
- Add theme class to the BODY. E.g. class="claro"

I plugged this in to a test page and it all worked for me: http://jsfiddle.net/sfoster/u3TLg/